# Custom url support in Android email

Tags: android

I am trying to port an iphone application to android. The application is supposed to be launced by a custom url that come as part of the email. The problem is that the email client coverts the custom urls from link to text (except for http,phone etc). Is there way throuh which i can add the custom url scheme to the default list when the application is installed by the user.

Comment: The email client is not under our control and hence the custom url are converted to plain text due to which my application cannot be launched. One solution that i found was to use http and then create a custom link How do I launch my app via a custom URL in an email but that does not work for me because the protocol is already fixed and it is custom. Is there way I can make the client linkify my custom url like it automatically does for http and phone numbers.

Willy, The name is the state of mind I am in and I hope you guys can pull me out of it. Thanks a lot for helping me on this

Answer (score 0):

When your app knows how to decode the URL, you call always call the intent for that particular application or service.