# Launching android application from Email

Tags: android

Is there any way to launch android application from Email, without using http/https ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom protocol, and install a custom handler in your app. Check [this out](http://snipplr.com/view/49930/). In this example, if your mail contains a link to `foo:do_something`, clicking on it would open the app.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514467/custom-url-support-in-android-email), the way around it is to leave HTTP URLs in your email, and have a webserver transform them into your custom protocol. This is fine if you control the emails.

I don't know if it will work by simply returning a 301 or 302 response - you should try it.

Comment: But emails does not support customized protocols. You cannot have a link with foo://. It displays as plain text. The example you suggested works fine only from browser.

Comment: i agree with the example you shared. The problem is, Gmail itself will not show the link. Since we are creating customized protocol, mail client renders the link as plain text.

Comment: Are you using Gmail or the Android client? Anyway, the solution is the same, have the mail client (or Gmail) point to an HTTP link, and then redirect to a custom protocol link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your email in HTML, with your link in an  tag:

`<a href='myscheme://myhost?data=whatever'>Launch App`

and before that you have to add this in the manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="ace" android:host="samuel"/>
</intent-filter>
```

while clicking on the link it will prompt you to complete your action by, then select your app from that.

Thanks.

Comment: i tried to send HTML page in many ways. Online html generators, Java mail. But Android eMail app is still showing the link as plain text. Any suggestion?

Comment: i don't want to do that Nikhil. If i do so it will show the chooser dialog with my app and browser as option. I wan to launch my app, like it works from browser.